# Magick++ always generates black images

Tags: c++, imagemagick

This is the code that should generate a bitmap:
The pixels come from GetPixels() a windows function that uses the device context to get the pixel. I verified that the pixel data are indeeed not only always the same number.

```
void Bitmap::writeBitmap(std::string filename, Matrix<COLORREF> pixels, int width, int height) {

    Magick::InitializeMagick("");
    Color* white = new Color("white");
    Image* image = new Image(Geometry(120, 120), *white);
    image->type(TrueColorType);

    image->modifyImage();

    Pixels* view = new Pixels(*image);

    size_t columns = 120; size_t rows = 120;

    Quantum* pixelsPointer = view->get(0, 0, 120, 120);
    for (ssize_t row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (ssize_t column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
            COLORREF cr = pixels.get(row, column);
            std::cout << GetRValue(cr) << "|" << GetGValue(cr) << "|" << GetBValue(cr) << std::endl;

            *pixelsPointer++ = GetRValue(pixels.get(row, column));
            *pixelsPointer++ = GetGValue(pixels.get(row, column));
            *pixelsPointer++ = GetBValue(pixels.get(row, column));
        }
    }
    view->sync();

    image->write(filename);

}
```

Comment: Is cout showing all zeros as well?

Comment: no it is not...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I had hoped your question would gain more traction.  Is it possible that image and view are pointing to different memory locations? You could find out by constructing another Pixels() object from image after the for-loop.  If this new pixel object contains all zeros, you have found your problem.  If you have already solved it yourself, I am eager to hear your solution!